# AT2005USBPK vocal microphone pack

Tags: microphone

Wondering if someone is using this bundle on Ubuntu Sonic Beaver? And if it is easy to install.

Cheers and thanks for any help,
Math

https://www.audio-technica.com/cms/wired_mics/210a1d3b9dbe734b/index.html?fbclid=IwAR1m38AyYy2x5PS8t2O8JlV3wyrsy9i_QqI1zi4OVw_pzJWP4VdVioZkVDM

Answer (score 0):

You mean Bionic Beaver?

Yes, a pack like this will run even on much older versions, and it's getting easier all the time.

If this is the kinda thing you want to do, you may really want to check out the packages in Ubuntu Studio. 
If you already have Ubuntu installed, you can just: `$ apt search ubuntustudio`
and simply `$ sudo apt install` the things that look good to you.

Or even easier, run `sudo tasksel` and check off the relevant boxes (using arrow keys + space bar) there.

You'll find there's a veritable ton of audio software for recording & doing virtually anything you would want to do.